# Azure: Caching tab is not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-configuration

Maybe my question is a bit stupid, but :)
I installed Azure SDK 1.7 (June 2012). And there is no caching tab in web role properties. What should I do to enable caching tab?

*I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you open a v1.6-based project? If so, that would explain it: You'll only see this with a project where v1.7 is specified. Look in the role selection dialog, when creating a new project, in the top-left corner:

[image: New project dialog]

If you change this to **Windows Azure Tools - November 2011**, the option for Cache Worker Role disappears, as does the Cache tab on all roles.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded project and Caching tab appeared